# Refresh tweets frequently in my site homepage without reaching to the rate limit

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am working on the site which needs real time tweets to be displayed to users. I have used Tweet Sharp library to fetch tweets.
My site needs tweets to be refreshed frequently, but sometimes I get {"The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests."} error.
As my site needs real time information, I have to fetch tweets frequently. How can I achieve this? How to get newest tweets without hitting to the Rate Limits?

```cs
 TwitterService service=new TwitterService(AppSetting.objTwitterClientInfo.ConsumerKey, AppSetting.objTwitterClientInfo.ConsumerSecret, AppSetting.objTwitterModerateInfo.ModerateAccessToken, AppSetting.objTwitterModerateInfo.ModerateAccessTokenSecret);

        var options = new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions();
        options.ExcludeReplies = false;
        options.Count = intTotalRec;
        var lstTwitterStatus = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(options);
```

Comment: Why not just use the twitter widget they provide? https://twitter.com/settings/widgets

Comment: My guess after a bit of googling is this; https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

Comment: I can't use Twitter widget, my requirement is different. I am working on site related to stocks. It needs data from multiple twitter accounts.

Comment: @dutt : yeah, I saw the document on Streaming API suggested by Twitter.But I am not getting how to implement it,as I am new to Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the streaming api like this:-

```
public void Can_stream_from_user_stream() {
            const int maxStreamEvents = 5;

            var block = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var count = 0;


            service.StreamUser((streamEvent, response) =>
            {
                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamEnd)
                {
                    block.Set();
                }

                if (response.StatusCode == 0)
                {
                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamFriends)
                    {
                        var friends = (TwitterUserStreamFriends)streamEvent;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(friends);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(friends.RawSource);
                        Assert.IsTrue(friends.Ids.Any());
                    }

                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamEvent)
                    {
                        var @event = (TwitterUserStreamEvent)streamEvent;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(@event);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(@event.TargetObject);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(@event.RawSource);
                        Console.Write(@event.Event + "\n" + @event.Source + "\n" + @event.Target);
                    }

                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamStatus)
                    {
                        var tweet = ((TwitterUserStreamStatus)streamEvent).Status;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(tweet);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(tweet.Id);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(tweet.User);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(tweet.RawSource);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(tweet.User.ScreenName);
                        Console.WriteLine(tweet.User.ScreenName + "\n" + tweet.Text);
                    }

                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDirectMessage)
                    {
                        var dm = ((TwitterUserStreamDirectMessage)streamEvent).DirectMessage;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(dm);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(dm.Id);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(dm.Sender);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(dm.Recipient);
                        Assert.IsNotNull(dm.RawSource);
                        Console.WriteLine(dm.SenderScreenName + "\n" + dm.RecipientScreenName + "\n" + dm.Text);
                    }

                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDeleteStatus)
                    {
                        var deleted = (TwitterUserStreamDeleteStatus)streamEvent;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(deleted);
                        Assert.IsTrue(deleted.StatusId > 0);
                        Assert.IsTrue(deleted.UserId > 0);
                    }

                    if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDeleteDirectMessage)
                    {
                        var deleted = (TwitterUserStreamDeleteDirectMessage)streamEvent;
                        Assert.IsNotNull(deleted);
                        Assert.IsTrue(deleted.DirectMessageId > 0);
                        Assert.IsTrue(deleted.UserId > 0);
                    }

                    count++;
                    if (count == maxStreamEvents)
                    {
                        block.Set();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Assert.Ignore("Stream responsed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                }
            });

            block.WaitOne();
            service.CancelStreaming();
        }
```